# Oscilloscope gear and ESD

Tags: oscilloscope, protection, esd, surge-protection

The answer might be obvious, but I am curious, how well are oscilloscopes and probes usually protected against ESD?

I noticed that oscilloscope probes are usually shipped in esd-protected bags. On the one hand it's just easy to always use these bags for all electronics equipment but on the other it could add up to the cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at "*Best Practices High Performance Oscilloscopes*" document from Tektronix or similar document from other manufacturer.

Oscilloscope manual should also contain comprehensive information, probably including ESD protection capabilities.

Document I mentioned says:

> CAUTION. ESD is a concern when handling any electronic equipment. All
>   Tektronix oscilloscopes and probes are designed with robust ESD
>   protection; however, large discharges of static electricity applied to
>   the signal inputs may damage the equipment. **A cable that is left
>   unconnected on a bench can develop a very large static charge that can
>   damage the instrument.** To avoid this source of damage, use the
>   following techniques to prevent electrostatic discharge into the
>   instrument:
>
> - Discharge the static voltage from your body by wearing a grounded antistatic  wrist strap when you connect and disconnect cables and
>     adapters. Your  oscilloscope provides a convenient front-panel
>     connection for this purpose.
> - Discharge the static charge from any cable before you connect it to the  oscilloscope or device under test by momentarily grounding the
>     center  conductor of the cable, or by connecting a 50 ohm termination
>     to one end,  prior to attaching the cable to the instrument.

Sentence about unconnected cable should explain why probes are delivered in ESD protection bags.

This is "better safe than sorry", but in some ESD-friendly environments/laboratories/workshops care about ESD is very important.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question. I feel a little bit skeptical about what they say in manuals though. They will never state that something is fully protected for legal purposes.

Comment: @EGDima It's not just about legal purposes. It's just written for any environment. For example probably you can use scope in 0% humidity laboratory. In such room you need to care more about ESD.

Comment: @EGDima Personally I never cared about ESD when using a scope in home workshop. I have old Tektronix TDS320 and it just eats all ESD produced on my desk with no damage or acurracy loss. However this is old, robust scope. With new models I would be more careful.

Answer (score 3):

A grounded 15pF probe should be low risk if the unit is grounded but your finger needs a string to remind you to wear a wrist strap. (1M to gnd)

But if you are lucky to have a 500MHz Tektronix differential FET probe, those FETs are rated for 25V < 1pF and  technicians hate engineers who bring in broken probes for repair.  You can blow those looking sideways unless you practise safe Test Engineering EOS awareness.

e.g. Always shake hands or touch someone before handing them a board handled by the ground , V+ rails

Comment: Finally, that's how you get an engineer to shake hands or touch someone!

Answer (score 2):

The oscilloscope and probe are protected fairly well against ESD however the object you are connecting them too may not be. You should always observe proper ESD safety when using any measurement equipment because what you are measuring may be static sensitive.