# Why we do not need wrist bands for ESD protection when using an iphone?

Tags: esd

When using high performance oscilloscopes, it is recommended to always operate with a wrist band connecting with ground through 1MOhm.

So my understanding for that is the oscilloscopes are designed with ESD protection, however not strong enough to protect it from any ESD.

Then why we do not need to wear wrist bands when using an iphone?

Comment: Nobody ever told me to wear a wrist band when using a 'scope. Where did you hear this?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107719/oscilloscope-gear-and-esd

Comment: What's the difference between an iPhone and an oscilloscope? (That feels like it should have a punchline - but really they are very different things!)

Comment: Nothing is "strong enough to protect it from **any** ESD" (think lightning and what not). Ok, maybe a neutron star (or a black hole) is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESD protection devices always have nonideal characteristics. When you're thinking about protecting an oscilloscope input, the relevant ones are leakage current and parasitic capacitance. If you're working with, say, a 1GHz scope, it only takes a very little bit of parasitic capacitance to significantly degrade the input signal, so oscilloscopes have to use low-capacitance ESD protection, and as little of it as they can get away with. That's likely to make such an input significantly more sensitive than something with lesser requirements on its inputs, such as a USB or charge connector on a phone.

Answer (score 6):

In practice if you work with an oscilloscope only you don't need a wrist band against ESD. The most sensitive points on an oscilloscope are it's inputs and they can handle 300V even on my cheap Rigol scope. That is 300 V continous so DC. ESD is a pulse, it contains far less energy.

Things become different when you use a FET probe with your oscilloscope. These FET probes are as ESD sensitive as any pin on an IC. But it's the FET in the probe tip that is sensitive, not the oscilloscope itself.

Devices that ARE sensitive to ESD are ICs and transistors. So if you use a scope to measure signals on these then you need ESD protection but that is not for the scope's sake but for these components !

In an (i)phone you do not interact directly with an IC or a transistor's pins. The housing of the phone isolates you from these. The contacts that are accesable like the charger input and the headphone socket are protected against ESD in a way similar to how an oscilloscope input is protected.

BTW all ICs have at least basic ESD protection build-in, without it they would be impossible to work with. However this protection only protects against ESD up to a certain level. Under bad circumstances this protection might not be enough. That is why an ESD wrist band is needed, it keep the amount of ESD in the safe region so that ICs are not damaged.

Comment: "The most sensitive points on an oscilloscope are it's inputs and they can handle 300V". You seem to imply 300V is higher than ESDs, whereas ESDs easily reach 10000 or 20000V. I'd suggest rephrasing to avoid confusing some people.

Comment: That is 300V continously while ESD is a pulse which contains far less energy. I have yet to see a device that can handle 300 V DC while being damaged by a 20000 V ESD pulse. 20kV is also a bit much, the highest level of on-chip ESD protection is 5 kV or so.

Comment: "The highest level of on-chip ESD protection is 5kV or so" - that's not because ESD events don't exceed 5kV, it's because on-chip ESD protection is only intended to protect ICs during the manufacturing process, not in end-user products.

Comment: I never said ESD events never exceed 5 kV. But in practice 5 kV appears to be enough. ESD can go up to any voltage. You cannot protect against ANY ESD voltage level so a choice has to be made.

Comment: Your comments are pretty much what I thought should be mentioned, all good (+1)!

Comment: (+1) Excellent answer! You might consider incorporating in the answer the clarifications you gave in your comments. They would make the answer even better.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with you that 300V DC implies high ESD immunity. As the other answer says, high speed scopes have little capacitance at the input and are therefore more sensitive to ESD.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I beg to differ. See [this OnSemi appnote](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TND410-D.PDF): "While HBM is usually sufficient for the controlled ESD environment of the factory floor, it is completely inadequate for
system level testing. The levels of ESD strikes, both the voltages and the currents, can be much greater in the end
user environment."

Comment: What I wrote does not contradict with what you just wrote. I completely agree with the OnSemi appnote. I made the distiction between IC testing and end user (product) testing.